# How to change array completely with a new array in React.JS with useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been searching everywhere to find this but all the answers are about just adding new items to an array with useState.

So imagine I have an array like this

```
    [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'take out trash',
          done: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'wife to dinner',
          done: false
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'make react app',
          done: false
        },
    ]
  });
```

Now I want to change it with a completely new array by using useState.

Like,

```
{
    [
        {
          id: 5,
          title: 'X',
          done: true
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          title: 'Y',
          done: true
        },
        {
          id: 9,
          title: 'Z',
          done: true
        },
    ]
  })
```

Comment: Is this array a part of some kind of data?

Answer (score 3):

- first initialize the new array :

```
export default function App() {
  const newArray = [
    {
      id: 5,
      title: "X",
      done: true
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      title: "Y",
      done: true
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      title: "Z",
      done: true
    }
  ];
  ...
```

- then:

  1- import useState and useEffect from React

  2- initiate your state

  3- set your to the newArray inside the useEffect function

  4- map your state array and return it to test

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const newArray = [
    {
      id: 5,
      title: "X",
      done: true
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      title: "Y",
      done: true
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      title: "Z",
      done: true
    }
  ];
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(newArray);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {data
        ? data.map((o, i) => <div key={i}> title: {o.title} </div>)
        : "loading..."}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: a working sandbox can be found [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-snyder-vkcd5x?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think it works with useEffect hook